# How to unpivot with multiple categories (1 w/ 4 columns & 1 w/ 5 columns) of data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a survey that automatically imports into a spreadsheet.

The survey displays multiples of hours#1 instead of putting it into one column as seen in Tb#1.

My goal is to convert Tb#1 to look like Tb#2 through unpivoting the columns so that it will be easier for my colleagues to work with the data.

Below is fake data but similar in format.

| usr | Company | Dept.# | Dept1 | Dept2 | Dept3 | Dept4 | Hr1 | Hr1 | Hr1 | Hr1 | Hr2 | Hr2 | Hr2 | Hr3 | Hr3 | Hr4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxxx | OS | 1 | Train |  |  |  | 20 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| xxxx | OPC | 2 | Poxy1 | Poxy2 |  |  |  | 45 |  |  | 38 |  |  |  |  |  |
| xxxx | Oxy R | 4 | H1 | H2 | H3 | H4 |  |  |  | 22 |  |  | 89 |  | 36 | 25 |
| xxxx | HPK | 3 | Test1 | Test2 | Test3 |  |  |  | 99 |  |  | 52 |  | 90 |  |  |
| xxxx | Mano | 1 | Porp |  |  |  | 42 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| xxxx | Macro | 2 | Otto1 | Otto2 |  |  |  | 75 |  |  | 23 |  |  |  |  |  |

I want it to look like this.

| usr | Company | Dept.# | Dept | Hrs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxxx | OS | 1 | Train | 20 |
| xxxx | OPC | 2 | Poxy1 | 45 |
| xxxx | OPC | 2 | Poxy2 | 38 |
| xxxx | Oxy R | 4 | H1 | 22 |
| xxxx | Oxy R | 4 | H2 | 89 |
| xxxx | Oxy R | 4 | H3 | 36 |
| xxxx | Oxy R | 4 | H4 | 25 |
| xxxx | HPK | 3 | Test1 | 99 |
| xxxx | HPK | 3 | Test2 | 52 |
| xxx | HPK | 3 | Test3 | 90 |
| xxxx | Mano | 1 | Porp | 42 |
| xxxx | Macro | 2 | Otto1 | 75 |
| xxxx | Macro | 2 | Otto2 | 23 |

I'm getting an error:

> "Object variables w/ block variable not set 91"

at this line `rgFill.Value = cell.Value` under actual hours comment.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TransformData()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet: Dim sh2 As Worksheet: Dim hdr
Dim rgDept As Range: Dim cell As Range:
Dim i As Long: Dim cnt As Long: Dim r As Long: Dim rgFill As Range: Dim rgHr As Range

Sheet1.Range("H1").Value = "Hr1"
Sheet1.Range("I1").Value = "Hr1"
Sheet1.Range("J1").Value = "Hr2"
Sheet1.Range("K1").Value = "Hr1"
Sheet1.Range("L1").Value = "Hr2"
Sheet1.Range("M1").Value = "Hr3"
Sheet1.Range("N1").Value = "Hr1"
Sheet1.Range("O1").Value = "Hr2"
Sheet1.Range("P1").Value = "Hr3"
Sheet1.Range("Q1").Value = "Hr4"

Dim q As Integer
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
q = 1
Do While Cells(q, 1) <> ""
   Cells(q, 8) = Cells(q, 8) & Cells(q, 9) & Cells(q, 10) & Cells(q, 11) & Cells(q, 
12) & Cells(q, 13) & Cells(q, 14) _
    & Cells(q, 15) & Cells(q, 16) & Cells(q, 17)
    q = q + 1
Loop
Columns("H:H").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Sheet1.Range("H1").Value = "Hrs"

'setting the sheet into variable - change if needed
Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1"): Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
'clear all cells in sh2
sh2.Cells.ClearContents

'the header which will be in sh2 coming from sh1 header as hdr variable
hdr = Array("Usr", "Company", "Dept1", "Dept2", "Dept3", "Dept4", "Hr1", "Hr2", 
"Hr3", "Hr4")

'put the data from sh1 to sh2 according to the header name defined in rgFill
For i = LBound(hdr) To UBound(hdr)
    sh1.Columns(sh1.Rows(1).Find(hdr(i)).Column).Copy Destination:=sh2.Columns(i + 1)
Next

'start row
r = 2

Do
'set the range for Unit Name according to the looped row into variable rgUnit _
this is how it will be pasted on Sheet 2
Set rgDept = sh2.Range(sh2.Cells(r, 3), sh2.Cells(r, 6)) ' sets the range of the Unit
Set rgHr = rgDept.Offset(0, 4)

'count how many data in rgUnit as cnt variable
cnt = Application.CountA(rgUnit)

    'if cnt > 1, copy the looped row then insert under it as many as cnt - 1
    If cnt > 1 Then
        sh2.Rows(r).Copy
        sh2.Rows(r + 1 & ":" & r + cnt - 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If

'fill the unit name
Set rgFill = rgDept.Resize(1, 1)
For Each cell In rgDept.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    rgFill.Value = cell.Value
    Set rgFill = rgFill.Offset(1, 0)
Next

'fill the number of actual hours
Set rgFill = rgHr.Resize(1, 1)
On Error Resume Next
For Each cell In rgHr.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
On Error GoTo 0
    rgFill.Value = cell.Value
    Set rgFill = rgFill.Offset(1, 0)
Next

'increase the row value by add the cnt value
r = r + cnt
    
' Don't change this one.
Loop Until Application.CountA(sh2.Range(sh2.Cells(r, 3), sh2.Cells(r, 6))) = 0  
'finish the loop when rgUnit has no data

'delete unneeded column
rgDept.Resize(rgUnit.Rows.Count, 3).Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Delete

'give the correct name for unit and color header in sh2
sh2.Range("H1").Value = "Hrs"

Sheets(2).Buttons.Delete

MsgBox "Data converted!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Try moving your `On Error GoTo 0` line outside (after) the `For.. Next` loop. Or get rid of that error trap entirely by checking the count of cells beforehand.

Comment: @CLR thanks. I have tried it but it doesn't work. I'm not sure if it is because of the SpecialCells because I'm trying to move numbers in each cell. That's why I had to used the Error GoTo command. I'm not sure what to do next honestly.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing that part of your code to:

```
'fill the number of actual hours
Set rgFill = rgHr.Resize(1, 1)
If CountConstants(rgHr) > 0 Then
    For Each cell In rgHr.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        rgFill.Value = cell.Value
        Set rgFill = rgFill.Offset(1, 0)
    Next
End If
```

And add the following `Function` to your code elsewhere:

```
Function CountConstants(rng As Range)
    CountConstants = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    CountConstants = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Cells.count
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks. I trying putting the function in but it's giving me an error to End Sub. I placed it before the first code since you have to define CountConstants in order to use it. I also tried placing after. Neither worked. I'm not sure if I should try another approach though.

Comment: The new function needs to sit completely outside any `Sub` you've already created. You can even put it into a separate Module if you wish.